# How to compile arbitrary templates/models using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, templates

I have a web service which returns a template e.g.

```
Hello {{Name}}, Today is {{Yesterday}}
```

Then I have another website which returns a json object

```
{
  "Name": "Mr. Been",
  "Yesterday": "a nice day",
  "otherdata": "unknown"
}
```

Is it possible to replace the keys from the template with the data from the json object?

The template and web service data is totally dynamic (unknown).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) service. It converts an string with potential angular interpolation expressions into a function that accepts a scope object and returns the interpolated string.

You would use it like this:

```
// get the template and data to interpolate however is necessary
var template = getTemplate();
var locals = getLocals();

// perform interpolation
var result = $interpolate(template)(locals);
```

There are some other options you can pass to customize how the `$interpolate` function works, so [take a look at the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) for more details.

Comment: That's awesome, wasn't aware about that `context` thing putted instead of `$scope` +1

Comment: It seems to nullify nullify the values it can't find (e.g. if {{Some}} doesn't exist it replaces it with an empty string). Is it possible to disable this behavior? The reason is that the same template needs to be interpolated with several models/json objects sequentially

Comment: @AnthonyHunt Merge all the objects together first, *then* interpolate.

Comment: I can't do that because a part of the template must be parsed when the client "sees" it and another part of the template when it takes an action. Isn't possible to instruct interpolate to "ignore" the variables not found?

Comment: @AnthonyHunt What do you mean "ignore"? Keep the interpolation expressions intact? In that case, no, you can't, but why would you ever want a user to see the expression with the interpolation expressions still in the string?

Comment: @AlexisKing if the expressions are not cleared out they can be parsed later. The client doesn't necessary needs to see them as they may be hidden.

Comment: @AnthonyHunt I still don't understand why you can't just keep a reference to the original template string as well as to all the successive objects to be interpolated, then just merge the objects you have and call `$interpolate` on the template with the resulting object.

Comment: The client may modify the template (it's a text area) so I guess I can't use an "old" reference because I would loose the changes. Is there any good reason why $interpolate "nullifies" undefined keys? It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @AnthonyHunt What would you prefer? Throwing an error would be the only reasonable alternative. Anyway, just keep a reference to the template *with* changes then.